# How to delete records that don't match by source table in SSIS using hashbytes

Tags: sql-server, ssis, lookup

I need to load table from source to destination in SSIS. Table contains approx 1.5 million row.

So far, I was able to insert new records into destination table that didnt match on ID column, and also update those rows that matched on ID but didnt match on `HASHBYTES` value.

This is what I've done:

1. using OLEDB source to connect to a database
2. using Lookup transformation to redirect rows based on ID column.
3. using DerivedColumn to get "RefreshDate" column
4. if ID dont match then insert rows into tblEmployeesDestination
5. using another Lookup transformation to see if hashbutes matches with
   destination table.
6. if hashbytes dont match then using OLEDB command to update rows in
           destination table tblEmployeesDestination.

---

My question is, what would be the best way to delete those rows in a destination table  that didnt match source table ?

What transformation should I use for that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on your table size (1,5M - neither small nor big) and number of deleted records.

- Number of deleted records is rather small (IMHO less than 10000) - then use OLEDB Command in DataFlow transformation as you shown. Problems here - each row generates a separate SQL command, which makes it rather slow and long-running.
- Number of rows to be deleted is not small. Than you can store pkey's of rows to be deleted in a dedicated table and then - delete from the main table using SQL DELETE command.
- Reviewing the approach. You can do almost all of your operations in a single t-SQL [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) command - insert rows not matching pkey's, delete rows matching pkey's and not matching hashbytes. Advantages - MERGE runs in a single transaction, but requires you get familiar with it and might [optimize table indexes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879317(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: #Ferdipux
I am using t-sql MERGE command right now. The thing is source and destination tables are on different servers. It takes around 15 (not sure if it considers long) minutes for UPSERT and DELETE.. Since SSIS was designed for those things, I thought using it would increase performance

Comment: @Oleg, I see your point. You can offload lookup from SQL to SSIS server, but the deletion is still due to SQL. If MERGE is not a way, I would recommend following the second recommendation - save all rows to be deleted in a dedicated table, and then - delete, checking the deletion command execution plan.